# wget: downloaded file name

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I'm writing a script for Bash and I need to get the name of the downloaded file using wget and put the name into *$string*.

For example, if I downloading this file below, I want to put its name, *mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg*, to *$string*.

```
wget http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg
45439 (44K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: «mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg»

100%[===================================================================================================>] 45 439      --.-K/s   в 0s

2011-12-20 12:25:33 (388 MB/s) - «mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg» saved [45439/45439]
```

Comment: maybe wget --content-disposition 'url'

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `basename` command to extract the filename from the URL. For example:

```
url=http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg
filename=$(basename "$url")
wget "$url"
```

Comment: Warning: This will not work for urls that contains redirects or dynamic content. Refer to est's answer for correct solution.

Comment: I like it!  But it also won't quite work if there are URL parameters.  For example `https://github.com/awslabs/aws-well-architected-labs/blob/master/Reliability/300_Testing_for_Resiliency_of_EC2_RDS_and_S3/Code/Python/server.py?raw=1`

Answer (score 51):

```
wget --server-response -q -O - "https://very.long/url/here" 2>&1 | 
  grep "Content-Disposition:" | tail -1 | 
  awk 'match($0, /filename=(.+)/, f){ print f[1] }' )
```

This is the correct version as there are may be several 301/302 redirects and finally a `Content-Disposition:` header to set the file name

Guessing file name based on URL is not always correct.

Comment: I like this approach, but unfortunately the awk in Debian derivatives (Ubuntu, e.g.) does not support the 3rd argument in `match`.

Comment: while not always perfectly accurate this is the correct approach.

Comment: In Ubuntu, you can use: `wget --server-response -q -O - "https://very.long/url/here" 2>&1 | grep "Content-Disposition:" | tail -1 | awk -F"filename=" '{print $2}'`

Comment: Modern easy way to achive it: `wget {link} --content-disposition`

Comment: @balbelias: this will correctly make `wget` use the name suggested by the server. But... how to retrieve it to assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 23):

You can just specify the filename before downloading, with the `-O` option to `wget`:

```
wget -O myfile.html http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: While not as "clever" as the other answers, this method actually has the advantage of simplicity and predictability

Answer (score 4):

As [PizzaBeer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574038/wget-downloaded-file-name/59492006#59492006), `wget` says where he's going to save the file. And that's important because it will ensure to not overwrite existing files by **adding a number at the end of the filename**.

So here's my solution with `grep` to narrow down the good line (`--line-buffered` is needed because of how `wget` works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158384/3970387)) and `sed` to extract the filename.

```sh
wget --content-disposition $1 2>&1 | grep "Saving to" --line-buffered | sed -r 's/Saving to: ‘(.*)’/\1/'
```

You can store this in a variable, which will be populated at the end of the download.

Comment: I found that the quotes on the `sed` command were formatted incorrectly, but this worked - `sed -r "s/Saving to: '(.*)'/\1/"`

Answer (score 3):

You can be explicit about the name like this:

```
url='http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg'
file=`basename "$url"`
wget "$url" -O "$file"
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle URL-encoded filenames:

```
URL="http://www.example.com/ESTAD%C3%8DSTICA(2012).pdf"
BASE=$(basename ${URL})             # ESTAD%C3%8DSTICA(2012).pdf
FILE=$(printf '%b' ${BASE//%/\\x})  # ESTADÍSTICA(2012).pdf
wget ${URL}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(wget $1 2>&1 | grep Saving | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]//g')
```

I like this because `wget` already tells you the filename it's saving.  The sed strips non-filename characters ie. the apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

```
~ $ URL='http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg'
~ $ echo ${URL##*/}
mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg
~ $ wget $URL -O ${URL##*/}
--18:34:26--  http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg
           => `mxKL17DdgUhcr.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Gowtham Gopalakrishnan's answer
is simply:

`wget --server-response -q "https://very.long/url/here" 2>&1 | awk -F"filename=" '{if ($2) print $2}'`

Which just outputs the name of the file that is set in the content disposition.

#### Example

```
$ wget --server-response -q https://hostname/filename-that-i-liek.zip 2>&1 | awk -F"filename=" '{if ($2) print $2}'
"filename-that-i-liek.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have the full URL of the file somewhere in a variable. Use Bash parameter expansion to strip the prefix:

```
echo ${url##*/}
```

Answer (score -3):

So you want to give the file / image name as a parameter.

Try this:

```
echo -n "Give me the name of file in http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/ :"

read $string

sudo wget http://pics.sitename.com/images/191211/$string ;;
```

I think this could help you