# grep with continuous pipe does not work

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, stdout

(maybe it is the "tcpflow" problem)

I write a script to monitoring http traffic, and I install `tcpflow`, then grep

it **works** (and you should make a http request, for example `curl www.163.com`)

```
sudo tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 2>/dev/null | grep '^Host: '
```

it outputs like this (continuously)

```
Host: config.getsync.com
Host: i.stack.imgur.com
Host: www.gravatar.com
Host: www.gravatar.com
```

but I can't continue to use pipe

**does not work** (nothing output)

```
sudo tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 2>/dev/null | grep '^Host: ' | cut -b 7-
```

**does not work** (nothing output)

```
sudo tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 2>/dev/null | grep '^Host: ' | grep H
```

When I replace `sudo tcpflow` with `cat foo.txt`, it works:

```
cat foo.txt | grep '^Host: ' | grep H
```

so what's wrong with pipe or grep or tcpflow ?

---

update:

This is my final script: https://github.com/zhengkai/config/blob/master/script/monitor_outgoing_http.sh

Comment: What is the output of `sudo tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 2>/dev/null | grep '^Host: '`?

Comment: @Inian now I add it in question

Comment: How does it fail? No output?

Comment: @ZhengKai: Is it a continuously increasing stream of data?

Comment: yes, no output, and it should be a continuous output

Comment: try to do sudo sh -c "tcpflow .... | grep | cut ..."

Comment: @linuxfan not works ToT

Comment: Are you sure you wrote correctly `sudo sh -c "... | ... | ..."`? Post the command and its output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is because of [`stdio buffering`](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/), you need to use `GNU stdbuf` before calling `grep`,

```
sudo tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 2>/dev/null | stdbuf -o0 grep '^Host: '
```

With the `-o0`, it basically means the output (`stdout`) stream from `tcpflow` will be unbuffered.  The default behavior will be to automatically buffer up data into 4096<sup>1</sup> byte chunks before sending to next command in pipeline, which is what overriden using `stdbuf`

---

<sub>1. Refer this [nice detail](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) into the subject.</sub>

Comment: Line buffering (`-oL`) is just as good in this context (grep operates on whole lines anyway), and should be a bit faster (not that performance would really matter in this specific case in all likelihood).

Answer (score 11):

To `grep` a continuous stream use `--line-buffered` option:

```
sudo tcpflow -p -c -i eth0 port 80 2> /dev/null | grep --line-buffered '^Host'
```

> **--line-buffered**
>
> Use line buffering on output. This can cause a performance penalty.

---

Some reflections about buffered outputting(`stdbuf` tool is also mentioned):

[*Pipes, how do data flow in a pipeline?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182242/148009)

Comment: Good suggestion.  It might be useful to explain what this does, and why it makes a difference in this context.